# rails webpacker angular - polyfills.ts - Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/reflect'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, ruby-on-rails-5, webpacker

Does anyone know how to get the latest Angular working with Rails 5 Webpacker?

I've tried a brand new install of Angular 7.2 in Rails 5

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install:angular
```

It fails with the following error:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/hello_angular/app/app.component.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/hello_angular/app/app.component.ts(7,14)
    TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

ERROR in ./app/javascript/hello_angular/app/app.module.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/hello_angular/app/app.module.ts(16,14)
    TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

ERROR in ./app/javascript/architecture_angular/app/app.component.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/architecture_angular/app/app.component.ts(20,14)
    TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

ERROR in ./app/javascript/architecture_angular/app/app.module.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/architecture_angular/app/app.module.ts(16,14)
    TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

ERROR in ./app/javascript/hello_angular/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/reflect' in '/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/hello_angular'
resolve 'core-js/es6/reflect' in '/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/hello_angular'
Parsed request is a module
using description file: /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/hello_angular)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
after using description file: /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/hello_angular)
    resolve as module
    looking for modules in /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript
        using description file: /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript)
        using description file: /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect doesn't exist
            .tsx
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.tsx doesn't exist
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.ts doesn't exist
            .vue
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.vue doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.js doesn't exist
            .sass
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.sass doesn't exist
            .scss
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.scss doesn't exist
            .css
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.css doesn't exist
            .module.sass
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.module.sass doesn't exist
            .module.scss
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.module.scss doesn't exist
            .module.css
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.module.css doesn't exist
            .png
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.png doesn't exist
            .svg
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.svg doesn't exist
            .gif
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.gif doesn't exist
            .jpeg
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.jpeg doesn't exist
            .jpg
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.jpg doesn't exist
            as directory
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect doesn't exist
    /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/hello_angular/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /home/david/Desktop/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /home/david/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /home/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    looking for modules in /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules
        using description file: /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
        using description file: /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/package.json (relative path: ./es6/reflect)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect doesn't exist
            .tsx
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.tsx doesn't exist
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.ts doesn't exist
            .vue
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.vue doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.js doesn't exist
            .sass
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.sass doesn't exist
            .scss
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.scss doesn't exist
            .css
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.css doesn't exist
            .module.sass
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.module.sass doesn't exist
            .module.scss
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.module.scss doesn't exist
            .module.css
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.module.css doesn't exist
            .png
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.png doesn't exist
            .svg
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.svg doesn't exist
            .gif
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.gif doesn't exist
            .jpeg
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.jpeg doesn't exist
            .jpg
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.jpg doesn't exist
            as directory
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect doesn't exist
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.tsx]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.ts]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.vue]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.js]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.sass]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.scss]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.css]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.module.sass]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.module.scss]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.module.css]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.png]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.svg]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.gif]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.jpeg]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect.jpg]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es6/reflect]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/hello_angular/node_modules]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/node_modules]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/node_modules]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/node_modules]
[/home/david/Desktop/node_modules]
[/home/david/node_modules]
[/home/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.tsx]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.ts]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.vue]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.js]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.sass]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.scss]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.css]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.module.sass]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.module.scss]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.module.css]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.png]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.svg]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.gif]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.jpeg]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect.jpg]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es6/reflect]
@ ./app/javascript/hello_angular/polyfills.ts 39:0-30
@ ./app/javascript/hello_angular/index.ts
@ ./app/javascript/packs/hello_angular.js
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3035 ./app/javascript/packs/hello_angular.js

ERROR in ./app/javascript/hello_angular/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es7/reflect' in '/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/hello_angular'
resolve 'core-js/es7/reflect' in '/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/hello_angular'
Parsed request is a module
using description file: /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/hello_angular)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
after using description file: /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/hello_angular)
    resolve as module
    looking for modules in /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript
        using description file: /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript)
        using description file: /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect doesn't exist
            .tsx
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.tsx doesn't exist
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.ts doesn't exist
            .vue
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.vue doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.js doesn't exist
            .sass
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.sass doesn't exist
            .scss
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.scss doesn't exist
            .css
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.css doesn't exist
            .module.sass
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.module.sass doesn't exist
            .module.scss
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.module.scss doesn't exist
            .module.css
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.module.css doesn't exist
            .png
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.png doesn't exist
            .svg
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.svg doesn't exist
            .gif
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.gif doesn't exist
            .jpeg
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.jpeg doesn't exist
            .jpg
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.jpg doesn't exist
            as directory
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect doesn't exist
    /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/hello_angular/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /home/david/Desktop/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /home/david/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /home/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    looking for modules in /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules
        using description file: /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
        using description file: /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/package.json (relative path: ./es7/reflect)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect doesn't exist
            .tsx
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.tsx doesn't exist
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.ts doesn't exist
            .vue
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.vue doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.js doesn't exist
            .sass
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.sass doesn't exist
            .scss
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.scss doesn't exist
            .css
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.css doesn't exist
            .module.sass
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.module.sass doesn't exist
            .module.scss
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.module.scss doesn't exist
            .module.css
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.module.css doesn't exist
            .png
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.png doesn't exist
            .svg
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.svg doesn't exist
            .gif
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.gif doesn't exist
            .jpeg
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.jpeg doesn't exist
            .jpg
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.jpg doesn't exist
            as directory
            /home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect doesn't exist
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.tsx]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.ts]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.vue]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.js]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.sass]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.scss]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.css]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.module.sass]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.module.scss]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.module.css]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.png]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.svg]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.gif]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.jpeg]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect.jpg]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/core-js/es7/reflect]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/hello_angular/node_modules]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/javascript/node_modules]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/app/node_modules]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/node_modules]
[/home/david/Desktop/node_modules]
[/home/david/node_modules]
[/home/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.tsx]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.ts]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.vue]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.js]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.sass]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.scss]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.css]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.module.sass]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.module.scss]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.module.css]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.png]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.svg]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.gif]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.jpeg]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect.jpg]
[/home/david/Desktop/klueless.io/klue-go/node_modules/core-js/es7/reflect]
@ ./app/javascript/hello_angular/polyfills.ts 40:0-30
@ ./app/javascript/hello_angular/index.ts
@ ./app/javascript/packs/hello_angular.js
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3035 ./app/javascript/packs/hello_angular.js
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a work around by doing the following.

Change core-js from ^3.0.0 to ^2.5.7 in

> package.json

Then execute in root rails folder

> yarn install

```
{
    "name": "klue-go",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^7.2.10",
        "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.10",
        "@angular/core": "^7.2.10",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.10",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.10",
        "@rails/webpacker": "3.5",

        "core-js": "^3.0.0",

        "core-js": "^2.5.7",


        "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
        "ts-loader": "3.5.0",
        "typescript": "^3.3.4000",
        "vue": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-loader": "14.2.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
        "zone.js": "^0.9.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. for others don't forget that it is package.json at your rails root app